# GridLayoutManager gets wrong anchor position (always 0) for save state, so scroll position can't be saved/restored correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm trying to use this tutorial https://panavtec.me/retain-restore-recycler-view-scroll-position  (which I have already used successfully in other projects) to restore the scroll state of a RecyclerView in a fragment after orientation change.
The saving and restoring itself works, the data is there... but it seems to be wrong.
I debugged it and when saving in onSaveInstanceState of the fragment...

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Parcelable rvState = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
        outState.putParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE_RV_STATE, rvState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(INSTANCE_STATE_ENTRIES, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) mAdapter.getViewItems());
    }
```

...I investigated the rvState and compared it to the state I get in the other app where scroll state saving in a RecyclerView (in an activity though...) worked as intended.

I know these values from the debugger won't help too much, but I can see that for the app where it's working, I get a savedInstanceState in onCreate that shows an anchor offset and an anchor position, both != 0, in the debugger.
 When restoring this state to the RecyclerView, the scroll state is correctly restored.

In the app with the fragment, the layout manager's save state shows these values both as 0 in the debugger (no matter how far down I scroll), not only at restore, but already when saving it.
So to me it looks like the scroll postion (or anchor position, whatever) can't be correctly determined. So of course when restoring this state it doesn't scroll anywhere.

In both cases I'm using the GridLayoutManager.

Anything obvious I'm doing wrong or that I forgot? I'm not really sure what code to post, because it seems all very straightforward...

I add the fragment in the activity's onCreate using the SupportFragmentManger, but only if there is no saved instance state, in order to not overwrite the fragment present.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fl_container, MyFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

In the fragment I save the state in onSaveInstanceState (see first method posted) and restore it in the onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entries, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.rv_entries);
    mProgressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.pb_loading);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), getSpanCount(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSavedEntries = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(INSTANCE_STATE_ENTRIES);
        mRecyclerViewState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE_RV_STATE);

        if (mSavedEntries != null) {
           mAdapter.setViewItems(mSavedEntries);
        }

        if(mRecyclerViewState != null) {
            layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(mRecyclerViewState);
        }
    }

    (...)

    return v;
}
```

Any hint would be appreciated...

**EDIT:**
Since Cheticamp asked: the version I'm using as declared in my gradle file is *recyclerview-v7:26.1.0* and when I remove all of the save instance state stuff, the RecyclerView doesn't restore its state on its own. I also tried leaving in only the part that restores the entries. This doesn't change anything either.

Comment: Which version of `RecyclerView` are you using? If you take all the saved instance state stuff out, does the `RecyclerView` not preserve the state on its own?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I tried it and added my results in the original question.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/Cheticamp/0fe38930be6929e59ce228d4473d7b29) is a simple app in two files that demonstrate how `RecyclerView` _can_ preserve scroll position. Maybe you can use this little demo to understand what is going on with your `RecyclerView`. You can also take a look at [Android scroll position restoring done right](https://medium.com/@dimezis/android-scroll-position-restoring-done-right-cff1e2104ac7); It might give you some good ideas.

Comment: Debugging your example pointed me the right direction! Thank you so much!
The view ids were the problem here... The fragment used has different layout files for portrait and landscape. In landscape I had assigned the outer relative layout an id, in order to determine if it's landscape or not by finding the view. So the whole view state would be lost on orientation change. *facepalm*
I changed my "see if it's landscape" to a newly added dummy view, now everything works just fine, even without explicitly saving the scroll state.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a LinearLayoutManager and found that it was because I was using a NestedScrollView before my RecyclerView in XML.

Comment: The same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: It is not a good practice to use RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView, recycling is totally lost. I recommend passing all items on the screen into RecyclerView.

Comment: I found solution for my problem with nested scrollview. The state could be saved correctly if widget has an id in layout.